# Facebook LoginManager Callback/PrepareforSegue Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to pass a property to my next VC using prepareforSegue. It is called, however my other VC does not load.

Original

```
@IBAction func onSignupPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(permissions,
    fromViewController: self) { result, error in
    guard error == nil else { print("Login Error"); return }
    guard result.grantedPermissions.contains("email") else {
        print("No Email Permissions"); return }
    self.getFBUserData()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

I've been able to get the next VC showing by doing calling my doLogin function below.  And there I instantiate a VC from the storyboard and present it. I believe it is due to the timing of the Facebook login window that pops up and closes.  I searched for a delegate method, but have not found anything

```
@IBAction func onSignupPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(permissions,
    fromViewController: self) { result, error in
    guard error == nil else { print("Login Error"); return }
    guard result.grantedPermissions.contains("email") else {
        print("No Email Permissions"); return }
    self.getFBUserData()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)
        }
    }
}

func getFBUserData(){

    let params = "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large),friends, email, birthday, work, photos, education, location, hometown, religion, likes, about"

    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":params]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil){
                //everything works print the user data
                print(result)
                let resultdict = result as? NSDictionary
                self.user = Mapper<User>().map(result)
                self.doLogin()
            }

        }) 

    }

}


func doLogin() {
        let successVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginSucessViewController")
        self.presentViewController(successVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
          }
```

Comment: Just to clarify what is going wrong here. You have a `prepareForSegue`method where you are setting a property on the designationVC. (I am guessing the property is something coming back from this graph API call). Next you state "it is called", guessing you mean the prepareForSegue is called? Is the successVC shown? with wrong or no data? or not shown at all?
Looks like the `performSegue` might be called before your GraphRequest returns.

Comment: I can only access my successVC with the instantiatevc method which does not call prepareforsegue.  And as a result my property that I am setting on my destinationVC is nil

Answer (score 0):

Very silly mistake!  Didn't realize I could simply set the property of instantiating the VC!

```
func doLogin() {

        let successVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginSucessViewController") as! LoginSucessViewController
        successVC.currentUser = user
        self.presentViewController(successVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```